# Rewrite rules are not over riding the links

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a content which has a link. The link refers to another website. Hence I desire to open the link in a new tab of the browser.

I have used the Rewrite results where I have given the tool tip and the target as _blank.
Both of these are not reflected in the site. When I view source, the link does not have the tool tip(alt tag) and also the target="_blank". That is there is no effect even after adding the rewrite rules.

What might be the problem? I'm able to add/ edit the rewrite rules. But it does not have effect in the site.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter a link path for the rewriting to take effect.

Expand the 'Replacement patterns' panel below where you've entered _blank as the target of the link. In there you will see what token you need to use for the link path. I expect it will be `[field_webcast_link]` or something similar.

I also notice you've entered 'Watch Web Cast' as the title for the link. That field populates the HTML `title` attribute of the link - which may be your intention - but if you want to display this as the actual text content of the link you will want to tick the 'Rewrite the output of this field' checkbox and enter the text there.

Comment: It worked Fantastic. I have used [field_webcast_link_new-url]  in link path.